# Insert All Data From DataGridView to Excel DataBase

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview

I'm a newbie in vb.net and programming language.

I have a DataGridView that data from Excel.
In my Excel; I have 3 sheets with same columns(4).

```
dgv = datagridview
```

dgv's data coming from Excel's sheet1 and Sheet2. (with Select Union Command).

My question is, how can I insert data from dgv to sheet3?

Comment: Duplicate question to many other, including the newest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156031/vb-net-datagridview-to-excel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.net DataGridView to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156031/vb-net-datagridview-to-excel)